# Program in java that reads data from a text file

Tags: java

```
date                 time               kg

12/10/2013        00.00.01              1   
13/11/2013        00.00.05              2   
17/12/2013        00.00.90              5   
21/12/2013        00.00.23              6   
27/12/2013        00.00.43              9
```

I have these data in an txt file. I would like to make o program in java that would read these data. I ' ve written the code above but I have mistakes. Could someone help me? The data have space between each other.

```
import java.io*;

public class ReadTextfile{
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      File file = new File ("test.txt");
      StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
      BufferedReader reader = null;

try {
    reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(file));
    String text = null;

    while ((text = reader.readLine()) !=null) {
           line.append(text)
               .append(System.getProperty ("line.separator"));
    }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally {
    try {
        if (reader !=null){
            reader.close();
    }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    System.out.println(line.toString());
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what mistakes you've made?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: what issue you are getting ???

Comment: first of all import java.io*; === import java.io.*; , be careful with the dot before * , I hope you know what problem it may cause

Comment: What are you trying to do? read it how, into where, to do what?

Comment: If all you want to do it to read the file into a StringBuilder seems like you are doing it ok.

Comment: You should be beaten with a code formatter :)

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
```

This is unreachable code, since above it you caught `IOException`.

Note [that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html):

```
public class FileNotFoundException extends IOException
```

Your code won't compile. Remove this catch (You didn't even close it..)

Another thing, if this is not a type, you should replace `java.io*` with `import java.io.*`.

Answer (score 0):

boy you are only having some syntax problem

1 : replace

```
import java.io* with import java.io.*
```

2 : take care of your catch body being started and closed properly

```
try
{
// your code
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

here is the working code , compare your program

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadTextfile{
   public static void main (String[] args) 
   {
      File file = new File ("C:/Users/hussain.a/Desktop/test.txt");
      StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
      BufferedReader reader = null;

try {
    reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(file));
    String text = null;

    while ((text = reader.readLine()) !=null) {
           line.append(text)
               .append(System.getProperty ("line.separator"));
    }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally 
   {
    try {
        if (reader !=null){
            reader.close();
    }
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    System.out.println(line.toString());
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take the following approach:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadTextFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();

        while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();
            String [] resultArray = currentLine.split(" ");
            results.add(new Result(resultArray[0], resultArray[1], resultArray[2]));
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    private static class Result
    {
        private String date;
        private String time;
        private String kg;

        public Result(String date, String time, String kg)
        {
            super();
            this.date = date;
            this.time = time;
            this.kg = kg;
        }

        public String getDate()
        {
            return date;
        }

        public String getTime()
        {
            return time;
        }

        public String getKg()
        {
            return kg;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can pull out any information that you want to from the list of results that you have.

So if you wanted to print everything, you could do the following:

```
for(Result singleResult : results)
{
    System.out.println(singleResult.getDate() + " " + singleResult.getTime() + " " + singleResult.getKg());
}
```

You basically can do whatever you want to with the data.  This approach would also allow you to transform the data into different types before you even create the Result object.